# onClick function is not working in reactJS input component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, react-functional-component

This is my input component and when I am calling this in another component. But onClick function is not working there. Pls provide any solution.

This is input component

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './input.css';
import clsx from 'clsx';

  interface Input extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>{
   half: boolean,
   lableText: string,
   typeOfInput: string,
   garyBold?:boolean
   value?:any
   placeholder?:string
}

 const InputField = ({half, lableText, typeOfInput, garyBold,value, placeholder}: 
  Input) => {
    return (
    <div className = {half ? "halfWidth" : "fullWidth"} >
        <label className={garyBold ? "grayBold" : ''}>{lableText}</label>
        <FormControl
        defaultValue={value ? value :''}
        required
        type={typeOfInput}
        className={clsx('mb-1 inputItself')}
        aria-label="Recipient's username"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        />
     </div>
     )
  }

  export default InputField
```

And here I am calling my function( Login.tsx)

```
 <InputField onChange={()=> console.log('ok')} typeOfInput='text' half={false} lableText={"Email Address/ Username"}/>
```

But there is nothing appearing in console. Pls help if you know the answer. It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your component doesn't even have `onChange` prop

Comment: *"But onClick function is not working there."* - What `onClick` function?  There's no `onClick` anywhere in the code shown.  What "isn't working" about it?  Please clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its not triggering is because you aren't giving it an `onChange` prop. Custom components don't have the same intrinsic hooks you can use, so you need to pass them yourself.

Take a look at this...

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './input.css';
import clsx from 'clsx';

  interface Input extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>{
   half: boolean,
   lableText: string,
   typeOfInput: string,
   garyBold?:boolean
   value?:any
   placeholder?:string,
   onChange: () => void, // I added this
}

 const InputField = ({half, lableText, typeOfInput, garyBold,value, placeholder, onChange}: // And this
  Input) => {
    return (
    <div className = {half ? "halfWidth" : "fullWidth"} >
        <label className={garyBold ? "grayBold" : ''}>{lableText}</label>
        <FormControl
        defaultValue={value ? value :''}
        required
        type={typeOfInput}
        className={clsx('mb-1 inputItself')}
        aria-label="Recipient's username"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={onChange} // And this
        />
     </div>
     )
  }

  export default InputField
```